# Dialogflow Agent doesn't speaks responses with Google Assistant

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have a dialogflow agent created and released as the alpha version, while the conversation with it through the google assistant sometimes doesn't speak up the responses and just gives a text response while I want it to give voice responses too for every response. How to configure this?

Also when I give voice input then only it gives voice response, otherwise don't. I want to configure it in such a way so that it always gives voice responses irrespective of the type of input. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user doesn't want to listen to your response, they may have the audio muted. The Assistant will respect the user's input method and only respond with voice when deemed appropriate. This cannot be overridden.